# How to handle mobile keyboard in reactjs when using vh for units?

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a site where I use vh for the height of my components. When they click on an input and the mobile keyboard pops up it shrinks the viewport height therefore shrinking all my components on top of each other. I have seen plenty of vanilla js and app specific code. I'm not sure what to do in pure react javascript.